# pandas drop duplicates from a single column while keeping remaining row intact

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe like below. I would like to remove duplicates from only one column while keeping the rest of the row intact.

The logic that i want is -

For the column `Jan`, start from the last row

for the last cell, if the value in the second last row is same as the current value then delete just the cell value (don't delete row).

and continue till you reach the first row

```
sales = [{'account': '3', 'Jan': 'try', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try'},
             {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'try', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': 'try '},
             {'account': '2',  'Jan': 'bbbbb',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df
Out[105]: 
          Feb    Jan                               URL account
0  200 .jones    try  ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try       3
1         210    try                              try        1
2          90  bbbbb      ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why       2
```

Output that i want is as below

```
          Feb    Jan                               URL account
0  200 .jones    try  ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try       3
1         210                                      try        1
2          90  bbbbb      ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why       2
```

Comment: Is this what you want? df.loc[df.Jan == df.Jan.shift(), 'Jan'] = ''

Comment: "then delete just the cell value" but you have to leave something... `nan`?

Comment: @Vaishali it seems to be working....could you explain the logic..thanks

Comment: @roganjosh na is okay

Comment: For column Jan, you check if the value in current row(df.Jan) is same as value in previous row (df.Jan.shift()). If yes, change the value to empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, determine what consecutive values repeat, and then use `pd.Series.mask` to hide them. Thanks to piR for the improvement:

```
df.Jan.mask(df.Jan.eq(df.Jan.shift()), '')

    0      try
    1         
    2    bbbbb
    Name: Jan, dtype: object
```

You can assign this back to `df.Jan`.

Comment: I think you meant `df.Jan.mask(df.Jan.eq(df.Jan.shift()), '')`

Answer (score 1):

To replace it with `np.nan` you can use the following

```
df.loc[df.Jan == df.Jan.shift(), "Jan"] = np.nan
```

where:

- `df.Jan.shift()` shifts the values in `Jan` cell by one up:

```
0    NaN
1    try
2    try
Name: Jan, dtype: object
```

- `df.Jan == df.Jan.shift()` returns `True` for each row that has the same value in column `Jan` as in the previous row
- `df.loc[df.Jan == df.Jan.shift(), "Jan"]` first index select rows to modify, second column `Jan`

---

If you'd want to remove the first row instead of second, then in [pandas.DataFrame.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method you should specify `periods` value as -1.